# Dificuldade em passagem de parâmetros e argumentos em callback

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 funções, onde desejo, ao satisfazer uma condição na função principal devo chamar uma função externa, usando nessa função externa o parâmetro corrente na primeira função.

```
//1 função
function check_fields(element)
{   if(this.value === "")
    {   ...
    }else if(!filter.test(this.value))
    {   ...
    }else if(this.id === "input_nome")
    {   input_nome_Ajax(this);//<<-- Aqui quero chamar a 2º função
    }
    console.log(this.id);
}
//2º função
function input_nome_Ajax()
{   ...
    var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlreq.open("GET","functions/db/select_ajax_form_criar_conta.php?input_nome=" + this.value,false);//<<---Aqui o "this" está `undefined` ???
    xmlreq.send(null);//<<--Veja o final da linha acima ^^^^^^
    ...
}
```

O erro é que o valor que preciso na 2º função ele está `undefined`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `this` é interno à primeira função e passas como argumento à segunda, então a assinatura da segunda função deveria ser `function input_nome_Ajax(value){` e depois podes usar assim:

```
function input_nome_Ajax(value){
    var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlreq.open("GET","functions/db/select_ajax_form_criar_conta.php?input_nome=" + value, false);
    ...

// e para chamar:
input_nome_Ajax(this.value);
```

Se quiseres chamar uma outra função e forçar o mesmo contexto podes usar o `.apply` ou o `.call`, e que seria `input_nome_Ajax.call(this)`. Assim a função teria o mesmo `this` que a primeira, mas acho que neste caso não seria necessário.

Comment: Vlw man, a primeira forma não funcionou, mas com `input_nome_Ajax.call(this)`, foi....